# search for a single quotes in a string and wrap it with other characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse a csv file and in
 the process have come across some
 entries that contain single quotes. I have written the following regex to match more than one match of single quotes, iF the method returns true I am planning to wrap it in another set of characters
 however I am not getting the correct
 output

Below is the pseudo code:

```
public boolean containsChar()
    {

        String inputStr= "Niel O' Brian";

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("/'+");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
            boolean matchFound = matcher.matches();

            return matchFound;
    }
```

Comment: You get the CORRECT output. But perhaps it's not what you expected. Try to elaborate on that. From what I see, you try to match a slash followed by one or more apostrophes.

Comment: ahaneo, can you give us the string you would like to have returned?

Comment: @Martijn I updated the question with the output that I am expecting

Comment: @ahaneo: Where? I still can't see the string you expect as output. Could you give the litteral you expect for Niel O' Brian as an example?

Comment: He wants to get true returned - but then, he wants the correct answer, which is false as it stands.

Comment: the above method should return true if it was able to find the single quote.

Comment: @ahaneo, no, it should not return true. See my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just use

```
String inputStr= "Niel O' Brian";
return inputStr.contains("'"); // same as your expression.
return inputStr.contains("''"); // I suspect this is what you are looking for.
```

If you have two consecutive single quotes you may want to replace them with one

```
return inputStr.replaceAll("''", "'");
```

You may want to place the whole string in double quotes if there is a single quote with

```
public static String quote(String text) {
    if (text.contains("\"")
        return '"' + text.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"") + '"';
    if (text.contains(",") || text.contains("'"))
       return '"' + text + '"';
    return text;
}
```

its much neater to place double quotes around the whole field as Excel does.

Comment: Well my end consumer of the csv cannot handle single quotes in strings, hence I am trying to wrap the single quote between two double quotes, would the contains method be more efficient that the regexp, why I am asking this is because my input csv contains more than 100 columns and thousands of rows all these records would need to be passed through the above method for validation.

Comment: In that case:  `return inputStr.replaceAll("'", "\"'\"");`

Comment: Oh yea, and I wouldn't worry too much about performance unless the program really turns out to be too slow.

Comment: @ahaneo, See my addition of how to format cells written to CSV.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove that forward slash. Right now you're searching for a `/` followed by one or more single quotes.

Also, `matches()` checks the entire string, you want `find()` instead.

> ... I have written the following regex to match more than one match of single quotes ...

The regex `'+` matches a single quote as well. To match more than one quote, use `''+` or the equivalent `'{2,}`

But if all you want is to find exactly two single quotes, I'd go for Peter's suggestion. I'll leave my answer because it explains why your `matches()` fails.

Comment: Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'+"); returns false when used with the matches() method but returns true with find() method I would like to know why the difference

Comment: Quote: `matches()`: _"[Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())"_, and `find()`: _"[Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())"_